# Filling a vector of pointers to vectors is producing weird results

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

## Introduction

I have a code where I fill a vector with `integer` values and and push it into a vector of pointer to vectors as follows:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>*> set_of_vectors;

 for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
 { 
     //initialize vector
     std::vector<int> pos_vector;
     //fill it with 0s
     pos_vector.resize(10, 0);
     //fill it with integers
     fill_vector(pos_vector);
     //push into set_of_vectors
     set_of_vectors.push_back(&pos_vector);
  }
```

The problem is the output is really weird. The output should shou be equal to

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

but on the contrary I am getting the following output:

```
9617952, 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
```

---

### Full Source code

```
 #include <vector>
#include <iostream>

void fill_vector(std::vector<int> & values);

int main()
{
   std::vector<std::vector<int>*> set_of_vectors;
   
   for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
   {
     std::vector<int> pos_vector;
     pos_vector.resize(10, 0);
     fill_vector(pos_vector);
     set_of_vectors.push_back(&pos_vector);
   }
  for(auto & vec:set_of_vectors)
  {
    for(auto &v:*vec)
    {
      std::cout << v <<", ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
  
  return 0;
}

void fill_vector(std::vector<int> & values)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++)
  {
    values[i] = i;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why should one want a pointer to a `std::vector`??

Comment: because the L function from the library that I am using takes as parameter a `std::vector<std::vector<int>*>`. it's not my choice lol @ πάντα ῥε . They are nuts I tell you

Comment: What a horrible API, are you sure you want to use such crap?

Comment: yes @ πάντα ῥεῖ it's the library that the Lab uses lolololol

Comment: Is that in a school setting? Perhaps whoever designed that API should get some talking to...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is UB.

`pos_vector` is a local variable and will be destroyed when get out of the `for` loop, then the pointer pushed into vector (i.e. `&pos_vector`) will be a dangled pointer, any deference on it is UB.

If you have to use `std::vector<std::vector<int>*>`, you need to `new` a pointer:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
  std::vector<int>* pos_vector = new std::vector<int>;
  pos_vector->resize(10, 0);
  fill_vector(*pos_vector);
  set_of_vectors.push_back(pos_vector);
}
```

Don't forget to `delete` them at last.

Comment: @HaniGoc UB means, you might get anything.

Comment: You could omit the call to resize() as there is a constructor which does the same initialization (new std::vector<int>(10, 0)). This saves a small overhead where the default constructor has to construct an empty object before resize() initializes ist.

Comment: @Chiel The explanation of weird output is the same, but the difference is that you suggested op to use `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`, it should be fine to keep your answer too.

Answer (score 3):

Your are adding pointers to local objects. These local objects will be destroyed at the end of each for-loop and you keep a vector with pointers pointing to garbage ("dangling pointers").

You could define a `std::vector<std::vector<int>> set_of_vectors` and use `&set_of_vectors[idx]` to get a pointer for each element.

The following code creates a list of pointers from a list of vectors and can be used in your library call:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>*> set_of_ptrs;
set_of_ptrs.reserve(set_of_vectors.size()); 
for(auto& v: set_of_vectors)
   set_of_ptrs.push_back(&v);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to do something like

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
  std::vector<int>* pos_vector = new std::vector<int>();
  pos_vector->resize(10, 0);
  fill_vector(*pos_vector);
  set_of_vectors.push_back(pos_vector);
}
```

Your example leaves you with dangling pointers for `pos_vector` addresses allocated on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

You have to copy the vector into the array, `pos_vector` is a local variable and storing its reference will lead to undefined behavior as the vector is deleted once it goes out of scope. You should also define `set_of_vectors` as a `std::vector` of type `std::vector<int>` and not of `std::vector<int>*` as you do not want to store pointers there that will go out of scope.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

void fill_vector(std::vector<int>& values)
{
    for(int i=0; i<values.size(); ++i)
        values[i] = i;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> set_of_vectors;

    for(int i = 0; i<5; ++i)
    {
        std::vector<int> pos_vector;
        pos_vector.resize(10, 0);
        fill_vector(pos_vector);
        set_of_vectors.push_back(pos_vector);
    }

    for(auto& vec : set_of_vectors)
    {
        for(auto& v : vec)
        {
            std::cout << v <<", ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You can simplify your assignment considerably with the help of the `std::iota` function.

```
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> set_of_vectors(5, std::vector<int>(10));
    for(auto& vec : set_of_vectors)
        std::iota(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 1);
```